# Check which of the two buttons is clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a page that has two buttons with **id=btn-config** and **id=btn-json-config** that show the contents of two different files when clicked and has the functionality of saving the changes to that file.

The code for both files is duplicated so i am trying to combine them in the same .cshtml file.

```
<script>
$("#btn-save-code").click(function (e) {
        var connectionId =  sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var filename = $("#modal-title").html();
        var contents = codeMirrorEditor.getValue();
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var branch = $("#branches").val();

        var token = $("#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input").val();
        var dataWithToken = {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,
            filename: filename,
            connectionId: connectionId,
            fileContents: contents,
            repositoryName: repository,
            branch: branch
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dataWithToken,
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveFileContents", "Home")',
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveStepFileContents", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('hide');
                $.growl.notice({ message: "File saved successfully" });
            },
            error: function () {
                $.growl.error({ message: "Saving file failed" });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Currently when i press the save button i get both the "file saved successfully" and "Saving file failed". 
What i want to do is to check which of the two buttons is pressed in order to avoid the duplicate message.

I have tried

```
$("#btn-config,#btn-json-config").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "btn-config") {
            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveFileContents", "Home")';
            return url;
        }
        else if (this.id == "btn-json-config") {
            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveStepFileContents", "Home")';
            return url;
        }
    });
```

and

```
    $('#btn-config,#btn-json-config').click(function () {
        var t = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    if ($(t == "btn-config")) {
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveFileContents", "Home")'
    } else if ($(t == "btn-json-config")) {
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveStepFileContents", "Home")'
    };
```

but i am stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of wishful thinking here.

This `$(t == "btn-config")` is not even valid jQuery and neither is trying to set url twice

You need to do this:

```
var t;
$('#btn-config,#btn-json-config').click(function () {
    t = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

then later

```
url: t == "btn-config" ? '@Url.Action("SaveFileContents", "Home")' : '@Url.Action("SaveStepFileContents", "Home")'
```

Since you did not post your HTML, the above is the best I can do. However if they are radios or such, there are better ways